# what does #function mean here in this function any ideas?

Tags: swift

```
func viewController<T : UIViewController>(viewControllerClass : T.Type, function : String = #function, line : Int = #line, file : String = #file) -> T {
}
```

what is the meaning of `function` here any ideas???

Answer (score 1):

`#function` evaluates to a `String` whose contents are the name of the function in which `#function` appears.

This is described in the Literal Expressions section of this page: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html

Here, it would be the name of the function *calling* this one. It’s useful for logging functions where you want to log the function that triggered a log statement.

Answer (score 0):

It captures the environment `#function` name. Like assertions where they print out the `#file` name, `#line` number, `#function` name `#clas`s name and etc.

For example if you call function `A` inside function `B`, it captures `B` and it's class and the line lumber and so on.